# Find number of prime numbers between two big numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

I am given two numbers $n,x$.  I have to find the number of primes between them. 
 Difference can be up to $10^6$; thus looping will take too much time.  Is there any other way I can do it?

Comment: There are various approaches to [prime counting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), which is what your Question amounts to.

Comment: @hardmath my math knowledge can't understand those arduous formulas,could you simplify them for me and future nincompoops?

Comment: There is a simple approximation ([Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)), but an exact counting formula is necessarily more complicated.  The famous [Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis) is connected with adjustments to the approximation that make it into an exact count.  If you actually want to identify all the primes in a consecutive range, a [segmented Sieve of Eratothenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Segmented_sieve) or variant would be attractive.  Which of these would you like to learn about?

Comment: @Murad see here this answer to a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/777047/189215