# How to find recurrence of prime numbers with periodic function

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, prime-numbers

> The aim is to find a recurrence of prime numbers. So we'll take the trigonometric functions as they're standard periodic functions, like $\sin(x)$: we'll take as an argument of $\sin(x)$ the angle found before:

$$y=\sin(πx/n) \mid n ∈ ℕ, n>1.$$

Fixed $n$ the function gives as result 0 exactly when $x=n$ for obvious reasons and the other zeros are given for every k*n, where $k=1,2,3,...$

Then take $n_1 ∈ ℕ, n_1 > 1$, for all $n ≠ n_1$ and $ n_1 ∉ $ set of all zeros of the harmonics, $n_1$ is prime because there is only one harmonic that has the first zero in $x=n_1$. This harmonic is called **prime harmonic**.

The set of all zeros of prime harmonics are ℕ/{1} then we can build a function that preserves these zeros. The best method is the multiplication. If the first prime harmonic has n=2, the next number without the zero is 3. Then take the second harmonic that has n=3, the next number without zero is 5 and so on. With this method we build gradually a function $p(x)$:

$$p(x) = \prod_{n=2}^\infty \sin (πx/n)$$  where $x, n ∈ ℕ$ for all $n \in \sin (πx/n).$
This function $(p(X))$ is called **prime function**.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: All I understand is that you are giving a fancy name to the $0$ function. Indeed it seems that $p(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Do you mean $\sin (x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are formulas to generate primes in that fashion. In this other MSE question you can find [the same topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248940/wanted-to-know-if-this-is-a-valid-test-for-prime-numbers/2248961#2248961). As per my answer before, there is a formula for primes based on sines, and probably the theoretical base of yours is another way of writing it. It is based on [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem):

> $\displaystyle f(j)=\frac{\sin^2\left(\pi\frac{(j-1)!^2}{j}\right)}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{j}\right)} \cdot j$

So if you run a loop it should provide the list of primes and $0$'s as follows:

$[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11...] \to [0,2,3,0,5,0,7,0,0,0,11...]$

More information in [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776997/formula-for-prime-counting-function).