# Prove or disprove $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi k x}{n})}{n}=1$ iff $n|x$, and equals $0$ otherwise.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I know for sure it must be impossible that the function I put forth to only have all prime and only prime zeroes, but I have to be able to prove it to be untrue.

Below is the summation I have found:

$$f(x) = 2 - \sum_{n=1}^{x} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi k x}{n})}{n}$$

The exact thing I must disprove is that: $f(x) = 0$ iff x is prime, for integer x. If anyone can help me prove this to be false, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

EDIT:
I suppose at this time what I have need to prove or disprove is that:

$$f(n, x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi k x}{n})}{n}$$

returns $1$ iff $n | x$, and return $0$ otherwise.

Comment: You know for _sure_ that it's false? How do you know?

Comment: It appears to be the case that for all positive integers $x$, the double summation is equal to the number of positive integer divisors of $x$.

Comment: @quasi If this is true, then I better start writing about this. If anybody is able to prove this false in the meantime, I hope someone will explain how it does not work.

Comment: If it's true, you can "incredibly easily make a closed form of the prime counting function"? Can you show how? Note that $f(x)$ is not expressed in closed form.

Comment: Sorry, not closed form. Just a summation - still something special. It would be of form: $$\pi(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \sum_{p=1}^{x} \int_{p-\epsilon}^{p+\epsilon} \delta \Bigg( 2 - \sum_{n=1}^{\tau} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\cos (\frac{2 \pi i \tau}{n})}{n} \Bigg) \mathrm{d}\tau$$, or of form $$\pi(x) = \sum_{p=1}^{x} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{2i\tau} \prod_{n=1}^{p} \prod_{k=1}^n e^{ -\frac{i\tau}{n} \cos (\frac{2 \pi k p}{n})} \mathrm{d}\tau$$.

Using the Dirac delta or Kronecker delta allows for the nth integers up to x be added together as ones. And bam, a non-recursive form.

Comment: Note that the summation requires on the order of $x^2$ summands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113237/discussion-between-jackson-and-quasi).

Comment: If it is false, just find a counter example.?

Comment: I'm not able to find a counter example up to 10^10, but that's all I've checked.

Comment: Well then it's probably true!

Comment: Sorry, no time to chat. Forget about trying to find a counterexample. Instead try to prove that the double summation equals the number of positive integer divisors of $x$.

Comment: I know nothing of number theory, but I would start by setting $x = 1,2,3,4,5$ etc. and then manually expanding out the 2 summations and seeing what happens to the argument of $\frac{\cos(\frac{2 \pi xn}{n}{n}

Comment: I know nothing of number theory, but I would start by setting $x = 1,2,3,4,5 etc$ and then manually expanding out the 2 summations and seeing what happens to the argument of $\frac{\cos(\frac{(2 \pi xn}{n})}{n}

Comment: See, when I made that summation, it came from that the first summation, at least from my intuition, would return 1 if k was a divisor of p, and 0 if it isn't. It seems to work for everything I throw at it, but I don't know how to prove it without a reasonable doubt. I suppose that is my goal.

Comment: Well if the first summation does that, then the rest is indeed trivial! But how does your intuition lead you to that conclusion?

Comment: $cos(2\pi x)$ equals 1 if x is a whole number, and the rest of the terms cancel out if it doesn't. I'll have to write it out.

Comment: @Jackson was writing it out already, the easiest way to approach that is with a complex geometric series —  remember $\cos x = \mathrm{Re}(e^{ix})$

Comment: Ah yes, I thought of that too. I thought of complex fourier series as well, but we'll see. Thank you for the idea though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you remark, it is enough to prove that
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2\pi Nk}{n}\right)}{n} = \begin{cases}1, &n\mid N\\0 & n\nmid N.\end{cases}$$
Note that since $n$ is fixed, it is equivalent to show
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n\cos\left(\frac{2\pi Nk}{n}\right) = \begin{cases}n, &n\mid N\\0 & n\nmid N.\end{cases}$$

First, if $n\mid N,$ we have $nm = N$ for some integer $N.$ Then it follows that
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n\cos\left(\frac{2\pi Nk}{n}\right) = \sum_{k = 1}^n\cos(2\pi mk) = \sum_{k = 1}^n 1 = n.
$$

Now, recall that $\cos(x) + i\sin(x) = e^{ix},$ so that we have
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n\cos\left(\frac{2\pi Nk}{n}\right) = \Re\left(\sum_{k = 1}^n\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi Nk}{n}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi Nk}{n}\right)\right)\right) = \Re\left(\sum_{k = 1}^n e^{i\frac{2\pi Nk}{n}}\right).
$$
Thus, it suffices to prove that more generally that if $n\nmid N,$
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n e^{i\frac{2\pi Nk}{n}} = 0.
$$
Now, set $\zeta_n = e^{2\pi i/n}.$ We know that $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, and we have $\zeta_n^{Nk} = e^{i\frac{2\pi Nk}{n}}$. Dividing $N$ by $n,$ we have $N = nq + r$ for some integers $r$ and $q$ with $0 < r < N.$ This implies that $\zeta_n^N = \zeta_n^r.$ If $\gcd(r,n) = 1,$ then $\zeta_n^r$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity as well, and if $\gcd(r,n) = d,$ then $\zeta_n^r$ is a primitive $n/d$-th root of unity.

So, we now need to prove the following:

**Lemma:** Let $n>2$ be a positive integer. Suppose that $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, and let $m$ be a positive multiple of $n.$ Then
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^m\zeta_n^k = 0.
$$

**Proof:** Writing $m = na$ for some (positive) integer $a,$ we can split up the sum as follows:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^m\zeta_n^k &= \sum_{k = 1}^{an}\zeta_n^k\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^n\zeta_n^k + \sum_{k = n+1}^{2n}\zeta_n^{k} + \dots + \sum_{k = (a-1)n+1}^{an}\zeta_n^{k}\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^n\zeta_n^k + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\zeta_n^{n+k} + \dots + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\zeta_n^{(a-1)n + k}\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^n\zeta_n^k + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\zeta_n^n\zeta_n^k + \dots + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\zeta_n^{(a-1)n}\zeta_n^{k}\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^n\zeta_n^k + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\zeta_n^k + \dots + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\zeta_n^{k}\\
&= a\sum_{k = 1}^n\zeta_n^k.\\
\end{align*}
So in fact, it is enough to prove that $\sum_{k = 1}^n\zeta_n^k = 0$ if $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity. However, we have
$$
\zeta_n^n = 1,
$$
which implies that
$$
\zeta_n^n - 1 = 0.
$$
Factoring the left hand side gives
$$
(\zeta_n - 1)(\zeta_n^{n - 1} + \zeta_n^{n-2} + \zeta_n^{n-3} + \dots + \zeta_n^2 + \zeta_n + 1) = 0.
$$
Since $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, $\zeta_n - 1\neq 0,$ and so
$$
\zeta_n^{n - 1} + \zeta_n^{n-2} + \zeta_n^{n-3} + \dots + \zeta_n^2 + \zeta_n + 1 = 0.
$$
But $1 = \zeta_n^n,$ so
$$
\zeta_n^n + \zeta_n^{n - 1} + \zeta_n^{n-2} + \zeta_n^{n-3} + \dots + \zeta_n^2 + \zeta_n = 0.
$$
This is exactly what we wanted to prove! $\square$

So, your function does in fact have roots at exactly the primes (supposing that the domain of $f$ is the set of positive integers). However, this doesn't make the Riemann hypothesis unnecessary. We've known formulas for primes for a while, see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes). I'm not an expert in analytic number theory, but I believe that part of the issue is that the formulas we have for primes are incredibly inefficient. Your formula involves a double sum which has a substantial number of terms, becoming rather computationally heavy as $x$ grows. I would recommend asking an additional question about why formulas for prime numbers (such as yours or the ones in the linked Wikipedia article) don't "make the Riemann hypothesis unnecessary," so that experts on that topic can answer and you can get a better understanding of how the Riemann hypothesis and prime numbers/prime number formulas interact.

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you. I will make note that the computationally heavy summation I wrote does not represent a prime formula. It is a formula for the *prime counting function*, which does not currently have any definitions other than ones including the zeroes of the Riemann Zeta function. This is why the Riemann Hypothesis is so necessary for this generally. That's why I made that, in hindsight rather pompous, statement.

Comment: @Jackson I'm not sure how what you wrote is a prime counting function: that should be a function $\pi$ such that $\pi(x) = \#\textrm{ of prime numbers }\leq x.$ Your function $f$ tells us when the input is a prime or not.

Comment: Additionally, there are known formulas for $\pi(x).$ For example, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776997/formula-for-prime-counting-function). Again, there is an issue of efficiency in such a formula.

Comment: The prime counting formulas I put forth are in the comment section. And you are right, I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

Your formula has a closed form.
Now first notice that if $n$ divides $x=mn$ we have

$$f(n, mn) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos(\frac{2\pi k mn}{n})$$

but this is simply

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos(2\pi k m)=1$$

On the other hand the closed form when $n$ does not divide $x$ is

$$f(n, x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi k x}{n})}{n}=\frac1{2} \left (  \frac{\sin(\pi(\frac1{n}+2)x)}{\sin(\frac{\pi x}{n})} -1  \right )$$

Since $x$ is an integer, we can remove $2\pi x$ getting

$$\frac1{2} \left (  \frac{\sin(\pi \frac1{n}x) }{\sin(\frac{\pi x}{n})} -1  \right ) = 0$$

So your formula is a form of sieving, linear. Riemann zeta function is based on sieving as well, but it condenses it and technically surpasses its linear nature.